# Is the OfBiz Backend UI intended to be used directly or just a fallback?

Tags: ofbiz

I am currently evaluating OfBiz as a customisable ERP solution for an IT business. It seems to be all powerful and stuff and brings a lot to the table. But once it is started and I login to the backend, I feel overwhelmed by the UI the click flow and how everything is presented in a somehow chaotic way. Is the UI designed as administrative fallback and one would usually develop a more approachable app with just the fields needed for a specific use case? Would one merely use OfBiz as dunno, a headless server providing backend services to SPA clients or e.g. some server-side page renderer? Am I missing a point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the UI designed as administrative fallback and one would usually
> develop a more approachable app with just the fields needed for a
> specific use case

That's what most [OFBiz service providers do](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Apache+OFBiz+Service+Providers). It's not a simple task.

> Would one merely use OfBiz as dunno, a headless server providing
> backend services to SPA clients or e.g. some server-side page
> renderer?

That's another option and I think some service providers do that after the "recent" (1+ year) REST put in

For more information better to ask on [OFBiz User ML](http://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html)